# Using azure cli from virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I need to use the azure cli from within a linux virtual machine. There are two contraints:

1. cannot use/store the credentials used for creating the VM on the VM.
2. the login/authentication need to be automated (non-interactive)

On AWS, I can use instance profiles for such scenario, but I am unable to find any feasible approach for Azure. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`az login —msi` has been deprecated (See [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/6111#issuecomment-381167912)) as of v2.0.22.

The new method is to use the `—identity` option. ie. `az login —identity`. See [az login](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-login) docs for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Azure CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/overview?view=azure-cli-latest), you can use `az login` with the `--msi` parameter to log in using the Virtual Machine's identity. See [the az login documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/index?view=azure-cli-latest#az_login) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it was resolved for me ,

1. you need to be logged in to azure portal in your browser
2. type `az login --use-device-code` in your ssh terminal
3. It gives you a URL and a code , enter the URL in the same browser that you were logged in to azure portal and enter the code in the pop up window
4. choose your email user for the azure portal  in the next window and
   you will be logged in to azure cli in your ssh terminal

Comment: This does not answer the question because op asked for an automated way. The way suggested here is manual and cannot be automated.